# How to add cells in a column in html

Tags: html-table

is there a way to add cells in a row column in html table without adding another table inside the row column
I have attached the image. and here is my code

```
<tr>
        <tbody>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><div id="span1">Units</div>
            <div id="span2" class="side-border">price</div>
            <div id="span2" class="r">value</div>
        </td>
        </tbody>
</tr>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: could you provide a JSfiddle ?

Comment: where is the attached image...? You want to add <td>??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have some different structure of your rows, you should check `colspan` and `rowspan`. The numbers should add up.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SKDzp/)

```
<table border="1px">
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">Hello</td>
    <td>World</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">col 1</td>
    <td colspan="4">CENTER</td>
    <td>right</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">Text</td>
    <td colspan="3">bottom right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you were to add the numbers from `colspan` they add to 6 and `rowspan` goes to 3. There are some things you have to take care of though. It's a little hard for me to explain now what those are, just try to visualise how you want your table to look, and then follow this:

1. The table should have the max number of rows
2. The table should have the max number of columns
3. `rowspan` used across table has to add up (more or less)
4. `colspan` used across table has to add up (more or less).

Follow that, and after writing the HTML for a few "complex" tables, you'll get the gist of it.